# Javascript 'Element' is undefined in ie but works fine in chrome and firefox

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I've got some javascript that runs correctly in firefox and chrome but causes ie to die with "Error: 'foo' is undefined (line foo.onclick = false in below code).

I'm trying disable an onlick function for an image while the page reloads.  Code is below:

```
function UpdateQueryAndRefresh(queryName, queryValue) {
    var escapedQueryName = encodeURIComponent(queryName);
    var escapedQueryValue = encodeURIComponent(queryValue);
    var upd_url = UpdateQueryStringParameter(document.URL, escapedQueryName, escapedQueryValue);

    if (upd_url.toUpperCase() != document.URL.toUpperCase()) {
        // Disable save button during refresh
        // Update current scale parameter also
        upd_url = UpdateQueryStringParameter(upd_url, "Scale", m_scale.toString());


        foo.onclick = false;

        window.location.href = upd_url;
    }
}
```

I've read that if something works in other browsers but not ie, that my header is likely wrong, but I checked the headers and they seem fine.  When I use the ie built in script debugger I can see that for whatever reason the foo image is undefined.

What am I doing wrong?

@JamieBarker
So I'm somewhat new to this language...  Foo is an image that's defined in the body of the page as an image. Here it is:

```
<img id="foo" src="images/image.png" alt="Show"  height="10" width="18" align="absmiddle" onclick="function()" />
```

Is there a reason that I can't see this in ie but I can in firefox and chrome?

Comment: I can't see where you're setting 'foo' to anything. I would EXPECT it to be undefined...

Comment: @JamieBarker okay, so somewhat new to this language...  Foo is an image that's defined somewhere above as an image.

Comment: Are you making sure that your page is loaded before this script gets run

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't setting 'foo' to be anything. You need to define it. Chrome and Firefox automatically assign variables to elements with the same ID.

```
var foo = document.getElementById('foo');
foo.onclick = false;
```

Comment: `Chrome and Firefox automatically assign it.` No, if you''ll try to assign its property without declaration. Try it in console for yourself.

Comment: @Tommi Yes it does. Don't tell me you tried it in console on this website? LOL. Here, try it on a [website that has a 'foo' id element](http://jsfiddle.net/dj3cna2y/). And use the firebug lite console, not your browser console.

Comment: @Tommi Jamie is correct.  Firefox and Chrome were correctly assigning it.  The code ran, and the onclick() was disabled.

Comment: Well, ok, I don't take into account that page has element with id 'foo'. But answer is incomplete (or misleading) because code in it will work **only** when this DOM-element exists. Remove this element and code will throw an exception. What I was saying in my comment is "chrome and firefox will not automatically assing window.foo for you when you do foo.onclick = .... It's here just in your narrow case."

Comment: @Tommi is your chi restored now? ;)

Comment: @JamieBarker It's much better now, thanks. P.S.: it was not insult or something, it's just for future visitors.

Comment: @Tommi I understand that. It would mess with my chi too :)